# How can I re-spec my abilities in The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've begrudged some of the choices I've made in regards to ability choices while progressing through the Witcher 2, and now that I've reached Act 3, I've heard rumors that some sort of "secret quest" will allow me to reassign all my abilities from scratch.

Are there any truths to these rumors? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Rumors online, or in-game?

Comment: Well the manual clearly says there is no turning back, so, I guess it's "Start New Game" for you.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the quest "From a Bygone Era". I see some mentions in passing to it on gameFAQs, but that's it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can,"From a Bygone Era" will work,but it is completly messed quest.I completed it by pure coincidence.

Here are some links that might help with quest.

http://www.gamespot.com/pc/rpg/thewitcher2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-59197966&pid=975399

http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/quest_from_a_bygone_era

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the quest "From a Bygone Era" allows you to reassign your abilities in chapter 3. So, it is generally possible, but only very late in the game. I did the quest myself and it worked, so it is not just a rumor.

The quest is started when you find a mysterious note you can't read in the quest "Little Sisters". You must hold onto this note to the next chapter, don't sell it to Deathmold when he asks. In the third chapter you will find a strange guardian in the sewer, you'll have to find out more about this note to get the password.

This is how it started when doing Roche's path, I don't if it works exactly the same for Iorveth's path.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a third-party tool to reset your talent points called [Witcher 2 Respec Mod](http://gq-game-mods.blogspot.ca/2013/09/witcher-2-respec-mod.html). It works by adding a custom function block when using the medallion. The steps including the following:

1. Download the [mod](http://gq-game-mods.blogspot.ca/2013/09/witcher-2-respec-mod.html).
2. Make a copy of your `CookedPC\base_scripts.dzip` file.
3. Replace the `base_scripts.dzip` file with the one from the mod.
4. Start the game and use Geralt's medallion.
5. Save the game and exit.
6. Restore your `base_scripts.dzip`.

Refer to the mod site for any more information.

---

In order to make sure that you can download the mod even if the link goes down, the author advises to send him a mail: `grail_quest (at) hotmail.com`.